# Setting and reading a default string for android app

Tags: android, default, setting

I am working on an Android app that uses a given url to download a file to my device. I want the url to be defined by the user outside of my app, e.g. through the "Settings/Apps/App info/" page. Is this possible and how can it be implemented?

Comment: You can simply set the url value by reading from File. Have you tried that? I would also just have placeholder url for testing.

Comment: That is a possibility. However, the user of my app would then have to enter the url into the file with a text editor or similar. This is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Text editor? All you need is an EditText field to collect the url and save it to the settings or preferences. How else would they enter the url?

Comment: I am porting the app from a corresponding iPhone application. There, the user can enter the url through the "Setting page". Similar to Android this page holds information about every installed app.

Comment: I have put up a picture here: http://www.forchheimer.se/iOS-setting_url.jpg. I assume a similar mechanism is available in the Android case?